# Dangling participial phrases starting with "there" or "it" as the subject

Tags: grammaticality

Dangling participial phrases starting with "there" or "it" as the subject. Does this sentence start with a dangler or is this fine?

> In taking into account the appendage that forms the aforementioned
>   sheath in the interior of the capital, it will be recognized that this
>   cast presented serious challenges.

Comment: You don't have a participial phrase starting with *there* or *it*.

Comment: I can't put my finger on exactly why, but I really don't think that first word ***In*** should be there.

Comment: Two unnecessary parts, both not dangling: 'aforementioned' and 'it will be recognized.' Did you mention the sheath before? Good, the reader will remember. Will it be recognized'? Good, then let people do so.

Comment: where's the dang participle?

Comment: Danged if I know!

Comment: The first clause, up to the comma, is a participle. It has the same unspecified experiential subject as "recognize" before plural and extraposition. I.e, `Undef` will recognize ... when `Undef` takes into account ...

Comment: Yes, thank you John Lawler, that's exactly what was confusing me: a sentence without a defined subject. I just didn't know how to call it. So then the first clause is NOT a dangling participle. Whew!